# Android M new permissions model

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

How can I detect if user choose in permission dialog "Don't ask again". I try to find any method for this, but doesn't find. This functionality is needed, for example, for hide some controls and don't disturb user with useless controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have asked for the permission previously, and now [`showShowPermissionRequestRationale()` returns `false`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale%28android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String%29), the user chose "Don't ask again" on some previous permission request.

Comment: Ok, I thought that there is special flag for such purpose. Thank you

Comment: such convoluted logic, the system should provide a clean way of obtaining this info so we can inform the user more easily what is going on

Answer (score 0):

There is way. You can find a detailed explanation in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html.

You can call the "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()" method to check if the user has clicked the "never ask again" option. If so, the method will return false.

And of cause you should know if you have presented the permission dialog once, otherwise this method will also return false.

Read the documentation :)